# R:intercept a part of one table to another table

Tags: r, intercept

[image: FIG 1 is data abd1]

[image: FIG 2 is data abd2]

[image: Fig 3 is data result,which the last 5 elements of column b1 are from the last 5 elements of column b2 and the last 5 elements of column b2. In roder to obtain data result,what is the code? How to move a part of one table to the other one?]

Fig 3 is data result,which the last 5 elements of column b1 are from the last 5 elements of column b2 and the last 5 elements of column b2.In roder to obtain data result,what is the code? How to move a part of one table to the other one?

Comment: You could use `rbind(df1[1:5,], df2[6:10,])` or `dplyr::row_bind(dplyr::head(df1, 5), dplyr::tail(df2, 5))`

Comment: How about colomn a1 of FIG2 is c(2,1,4,5,7,3,8,10,9,6).How to obtain a table which merges FIG1 and FIG2 with the sort of a1 in FIG1?